# Integrating blogdown with DataCamp Light

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm running a `blogdown` powered [blog](https://kamil.sijko.pl). I  recently noticed [DataCamp Light project](https://github.com/datacamp/datacamp-light) which claims to "convert any website or blog to an interactive learning platform", which sounds awesome (I imagine readers being able to run my R code presented on site or modify it slightly for better understanding).

Is there a known, easy way to integrate `blogdown` with `datacamp` interactivity?

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with the `tutorial` package by Datacamp: [datacamp.github.io/tutorial](https://datacamp.github.io/tutorial/)

````
---
title: "Example Document"
author: "Your name here"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
tutorial::go_interactive()
```

By default, `tutorial` will convert all R chunks.

```{r}
a <- 2
b <- 3

a + b
```
````